# How do I automatically install tex packages in Kile?

Tags: kile

I tried compiling a simple document in Kile and got a

```
File `arydshln.sty' not found. \usepackage
```

Error. Perhaps my opinion is too bold, but shouldn't this thing install missing packages automatically? I tried installing something called texlive, but didn't help.

So, what do I do to install those packages? On windows I installed Miktex and everything was okay.

Comment: I don't think Miktex on Windows is a good comparison.  Based on what you said, it sounds like you logged into Windows as a system administrator.  If you hadn't, I guess you would be restricted from installing packages.  (My guess -- I don't use Miktex.)  As for your question, you need to find the package and install it using apt.  And no, I don't think Kile should install it automatically; it is just an interface that sits on top of latex.  I guess if you think it should be that way, you should take it up with the developers of kile (https://kde.org/applications/office/kile/) and not Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, yes, I am the only user on my windows machine.

Comment: Ubuntu uses TeXlive distribution - it is very huge but universal and stable. You can search for needed [`arydshln.sty` on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=arydshln.sty) and you will get `texlive-latex-extra` as package name. This is how deb-packaging works. You can install only needed parts of texlive by using this way.

Answer (score 2):

This one is a little tricky,  If you had done `sudo apt install kile --install-suggests` you would have installed a great deal more packages, and through many of the 'suggested' packages you would have arrived at 'texlive-latex-extra' which includes the file 'arydshln.sty'

I'm generally not a fan of 'install-suggests' as sometimes it installs far more software than I want.

For example `sudo apt install kile` on my system will install 197 packages, loading 131 MB of archives

`sudo apt install kile --install-suggests` will install 1641 packages, pulling 4,352 MB of archives.

**In this specific case, I believe that you would be best served by**

```
sudo apt install texlive-xetex
```

This will pull in the package containing 'arydshln.sty', and about 20 others some of which apparently are wanted in your specific application.

**Further information and investigation**

You can look at the packages suggested for installation using the command

```
apt show kile
```

and at https://packages.ubuntu.com/ you can search for the packages mentioned to see what they require as well.  I used this webpage to search for the file 'arydshln.sty' to find what package it was contained in, and `apt-cache rdepends texlive-xetex-extra` to find eventually, the chain that led to one of the suggested packages for 'kile'

Comment: Okay, so how do I install this package?https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/polski

Comment: okay, apparently typing sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-polish fixed that, one would have assumed the installer would detect the language I'm using, but apparently that's too much. So yeah, thanks, your magical lines probably have helped as well :)